# How to fetch Item Key from Firebase

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

I want to get the item key of my data in my database but in as you can see in DataSnapshot function, I call try to fetch the item key but it return empty. I am trying to bind all item keys to my data fetch. So every item fetched should have its key in it so I can use the key.  But then, all other elements are fetched excluding the item key. Why is the item key not showing? Thank you for your help

**structure**

[image]

**Model**

```
 public Hero(string uid,string name, string achievment, string history, string quote)
            {
                this.uid = uid;
                this.name = name;
                this.achvievment = achievment;
                this.history = history;
                this.quote = quote;
            }


        public HashMap ToMap()
        {

            HashMap map = new HashMap();
            map.Put("Uid", this.uid);
            map.Put("Name", this.name);
            map.Put("Achievement", this.achvievment);
            map.Put("History", this.history);
            map.Put("Quote", this.quote);
            return map;
        }



        public string Uid

        {
            get { return uid; }
            set { uid = value; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }

        }

        public int Image

        {
            get { return image; }
            set { image = value; }

        }

        public string Achievement 

        {
            get { return achvievment; }
            set { achvievment = value; }
        }

        public string History

        {
            get { return history; }
            set { history = value; }
        }

        public string Quote

        {
            get { return quote; }
            set { quote = value; }
        }
```

**Saving data**

```
//this is how i save my data which works fine


 mHero.Push().SetValue(new PeaceHero(user.Uid,HeroName.Text, HeroAchv.Text, HeroHistory.Text, HeroQuote.Text).ToMap());
```

**Fetching Data**

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            var items = snapshot.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();

            HashMap map;
            foreach (DataSnapshot item in items)
            {

                map = (HashMap)item.Value;

                Hero.Add(new Hero(map.Get(item.Key)?.ToString(),map.Get("Name")?.ToString(), map.Get("Achievement")?.ToString(),map.Get("History")?.ToString(),map.Get("Quote")?.ToString()));
                Console.WriteLine("Sending item key" +item.Key.ToString());
                key = item.Key;
            }

            HeroAdapter adapter = new PeaceHeroAdapter(Hero,this);

            Console.Write("The key is "+key);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found an answer to this. This might help someone in the future.

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {
            var items = snapshot.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();

            HashMap map;
            foreach (DataSnapshot item in items)
            {

                map = (HashMap)item.Value;

                Hero.Add(new Hero(item.Key.ToString(),map.Get("Name")?.ToString(), map.Get("Achievement")?.ToString(),map.Get("History")?.ToString(),map.Get("Quote")?.ToString()));
                Console.WriteLine("Sending item key" +item.Key.ToString());
                key = item.Key;
            }

            HeroAdapter adapter = new PeaceHeroAdapter(Hero,this);


        }
```

Comment: What was the problem? Needing to call `Key.ToString()` If that is the case why was key not printed in `Console.WriteLine("Sending item key" +item.Key.ToString());`

Comment: I was trying to bind the item key on every data call in the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what item.Key is supposed to be but your Hero constructor should be:

```
  Hero.Add(new Hero(map.Get(""Uid"")?.ToString(),map.Get("Name")?.ToString(), map.Get("Achievement")?.ToString(),map.Get("History")?.ToString(),map.Get("Quote")?.ToString()));
```

Comment: please look at the structure of my database. i am trying to get the key of the item the is knz.......... not the uid of the user

Comment: What version are you using? have you tried `getKey()` or `Key().` docs on different versions have different methods. Also what is your console output?

Comment: i am using Vs, Xamarin so i use Key. In the console, i get all the keys.  Meaning when i request for the uid of a hero, it should return the hero's key and not the user's id,  but it returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting the Key is because you're looking for it in the wrong data snapshot.

Instead of the following :-

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        var items = snapshot.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();

        HashMap map;
        foreach (DataSnapshot item in items)
        { 
            key = item.Key

         ....
```

Use this :-

```
public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
{
    var items = snapshot.Children?.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();
    var key = snapshot.Key

    HashMap map;
    foreach (DataSnapshot item in items)
    { 
     ....
```

The logic here is that when you call `foreach(Datasnapshot item in items)` , then you iterate over the children of the parent Datasnapshot. Instead of this, you require the key of the datasnapshot obtained in the `onDataChange(Datasnapshot snapshot)` method. This is `snapshot`. Hence, you should call `.Key` on `snapshot`.

Comment: when i call `var key = snapshot.Key` it gives me `Hero` that is the name of the structure not the keys